# PHP .htaccess -> pretty url (in reverse)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I know how to make URL's rewrite, for example: 
`www.example.com/index.php?id=1&cat=3` to `www.example.com/1/3/` (or whatever). I know that.

What I don't know is how on earth to change my whole links in all pages to link to pretty URL's. All my site's links are old fashion (`<a href="index.php?id=1&cat=2">`) and there are many.

I`m asking if someone has an idea or know how to automaticaly redirect to that pretty url if the user click on index.php?id=1. (Almost like this site Stackoverflow if you change title in the url).

So my presumtions are...

1. Use .htaccess to read the index.php?id=1&cat=2 to rewrite index/1/3 that itself interprets again (strange)
2. a php file to do the redirects that htaccess rewrites back to original...

Conclusion: change `<a href="index.php?id=1&.....">` automaticaly to `index/1/2`

---

### SOLVED

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##################################
# This turns index.php?id=1&cat=2 into index/1/2 and then back 'transparent' into    index.php?id=1&cat=2 if you have old fashioned
# links in your site and don't want to change them :)


# Avoid mod_rewrite infinite loops 
# This is critical if you want to use this code

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Hard-rewrite ("[R]") to "friendly" URL.
# Needs RewriteCond to match original querystring.
# Uses "?" in target to remove original querystring,
#   and "%n" backrefs to move its components.
# Target must be a full path as it's a hard-rewrite.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&cat=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://localhost/index/%1/%2/? [L,R]

# Soft-rewrite from "friendly" URL to "real" URL.
# Transparent to browser.
# Won't re-trigger the above rewrite, though I'm
#   not really sure why! The order of the rules
#   doesn't seem to make a difference.
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ index.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevents browser looping, which does seem
#   to occur in some specific scenarios. Can't
#   explain the mechanics of this problem in
#   detail, but there we go.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Hard-rewrite ("[R]") to "friendly" URL.
# Needs RewriteCond to match original querystring.
# Uses "?" in target to remove original querystring,
#   and "%n" backrefs to move its components.
# Target must be a full path as it's a hard-rewrite.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&cat=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/index/%1/%2/? [L,R]

# Soft-rewrite from "friendly" URL to "real" URL.
# Transparent to browser.
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ /index.php?id=$1&cat=$2
```

Of course, ideally, you'd just fix your links, and then you'd only require the soft-rewrite. :)

<sub>Tested with Apache/2.2.3. I think I made up the terms "hard-rewrite" and "soft-rewrite".</sub>

Comment: that's the trick if it will result in infinite loop and i guess it will , because at the bottom of that will have   `RewriteRule ^(index)/([a-z0-9]+)(/[^/]+)?/([a-z0-9]+)(/[^/]+)?/?(.*)$ index.php?param1=$2&param2=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index)/([a-z0-9]+)(/[^/]+)?/?(.*)$ index.php?param1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @pufos: I'm honestly not sure whether it will or not. That the two rules have different flags _may_ prevent the loop (as the first makes the browser do an explicit re-request, whereas the second just silently rewrites the target location). But it will need checking. I'm openly willing to accept that this may not work.

Comment: `result: not working ... if i try to access the file from index.php?id=1&... it does'n rewrite it to /index/1/3 it leave it like that index.php?id=.... `

Comment: it's just mind-blowing and i can't figure it our logically .. yet :(

Comment: Chrome said "Redirecting loop " :|

Comment: @pufos: :( My Firefox didn't. Can you send me an URL to your test page? Your browser certainly shouldn't see a loop because the soft-rewrite is completely transparent to it; if anything I'd have been looking out for a loop on the server-side. And what's the contents of your `index.php`? I just had `<?php print_r($_SERVER) ?>` in mine.

Comment: @Tomalak change the last line of htaccess to this `^(index)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ index.php?id=$2&cat=$3` because $1 will be index not the value .. and will become a loop .. i'll give a like ... few seconds to conect to dyn.

Comment: @pufos: But that's not what I wrote... and it still works for my testcase. Admittedly my paths are different. I'll try to get my testcase even closer to yours.

Comment: if i leave the last line as you wrote .. it say "Object not found" -- i have /localhost/permalink/index.php and added `RewriteBase /permalink/` ** the first 2 lines are working perfect .. but revers not working leaving the line that way **

Comment: @pufos: After a few tweaks, I've now managed to get it looping in the browser too. But I'm not entirely sure how!

Comment: @pufos: Edited with a compromise approach.

Comment: @Tomalak - i managed to stop the infinite loops ... just add this `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]` and tell me the results

Comment: @Tomalak - add the 2 line at the top .. just before RewriteEngine on

Comment: @pufos: Yep, good job. :) I still can't quite figure out what triggers the loop in only some cases, which is frustrating, but there we go. BTW it should still go _under_ `RewriteEngine on`; you just happen to already have the engine on in your global config.

Comment: @pufos: Backticks; you can't do blockquotes in comments. Feel free to post your own answer to the question, though I've already stolen your findings and edited mine. :)

Comment: @Tomalak it does't matter - as more as these post's users cand find clear answer . Your answer was sharp already , we just tuned it to perfect :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: @pufos: No problem. I'm still trying to figure out under what conditions the redirect loop occurs, why, and how! Do let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: i found out this post about apache (i think it's an apache problem) : Apache 2.0.45:
Prevent endless loops of internal redirects in mod_rewrite by
aborting after exceeding a limit of internal redirects. The
limit defaults to 10 and can be changed using the RewriteOptions
directive. PR 17462. [André Malo]

Comment: @pufos: I think that I was getting no redirect loop due to having another test querystring var on the target URI (`test.php?id=$1&cat=$2&lol=wtf`); this caused the initial `RewriteCond` not to match. Anyway, the second rule *is* causing the entire script to start from scratch, hence the loop. This is surprising to me but there we go. So the check on `REDIRECT_STATUS` will always be required.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes that rule will always be necesary and will solve the mod_rewrite looping problem. But this should be a feature of Apache at the core of mod_rewrite to stop this loop whithout us having to manualy set this rule. `I'm glad we find out the solution to this problem but there are still a very large number of people complainig loops and they have no solution to the problem` :) sad

Comment: @pufos: Something to do with `[L]`+`[R]` causes the loop. I still can't really figure out the mechanics of it. Anyway, changing `[L,R]` to `[R]` appears to remove the need for the `REDIRECT_STATUS` check...

Comment: @pufos: Actually ignore my last comment; have rolled back my latest edit. I give up trying to figure this out. At least it works, though. :)

Comment: @Tomalak :)) programing languages are hard work and sometimes understanding them is even harder. I was going to figure myself out why was doing that but still no clue. Logically is was going in loop mode but i don't know why

Comment: @pufos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574442/why-does-this-cause-an-infinite-request-loop

Comment: @Tomalak Do you think that anyone knows the answer to this question. I hardly wait for it :) (unless i find it first :) )

Comment: @pufo: I hope so. :) BTW on SO, if the question has been solved, it's better to write an answer yourself (or to accept an existing one) than to write the solution in a question edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change your index.php file to do it? You could theoretically do a little more error checking that way, allowing for the variables to be in any order and still get routed to the correct end location.

```
<?php
    // Permanent redirection
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/{$_GET['id']}/{$_GET['cat']}");
```

I didn't do any error checking here, but wanted to give a base example.

On second thought I guess this is adding in functionality to the index.php file which you then want to use for your application itself, so perhaps it would end up confusing the functionality in the code.

Comment: You say ... to do the matching patterns in index.php ? Or should i redirect all pages to single page and do matching pattern`s there. But i don;t know how because i have index.php , edit.php, insert.php, run.php and every of those php file are generating link `old fashion` like `<a href=index.php?id.....>` and what about the menu of the site which like tu category.php?cat=12 ..

Comment: Well, for the "pretty" urls to work, you'll have to have a redirect in place for them. You could theoretically have that redirect result as application.php (I just picked a name at random), that would allow the two pieces to still exist separately but have your functionality. You don't really have to do any matching in the index.php as those values would be made magically available in the PHP superglobals (that's what $_GET is one of). So you can refer to them from that array, e.g. $_GET['id'] would give you '1' from your example.

Comment: Ahh, ok, then yes, it's a bit more complicated if the URLs are plentiful. You're probably going to have to case them out explicitly, as you're going to have some possible clashing between your new pretty URLs and how they are handled. You could then redirect all (.*)\.php(.*) URLs to a redirector.php file which would then redirect to the end result, but 2 phase redirects are not the best. So you're left with a more complex regex which I'll have to ponder upon.

Comment: Yes because i want to maintain the `<a href=index.php?id...>` and when clicked to link to `http://example.com/index/1/3/` to let `.htaccess` interpret it and rewrite it to `index.php?id=$1` :( ....how to figure this out ?