# Why does this cause an infinite request loop?

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

Earlier today, I was helping someone with an `.htaccess` use case, and [came up with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573485/php-htaccess-pretty-url-in-reverse/5573650#5573650) that works but can't quite figure it out myself!

He wanted to be able to:

- Browse to `index.php?id=3&cat=5`
- See the location bar read `index/3/5/`
- Have the content served from `index.php?id=3&cat=5`

The last two steps are fairly typical (usually from the user entering `index/3/5` in the first place), but the first step was required because he still had some old-format links in his site and, for whatever reason, couldn't change them. So he needed to support *both* URL formats, and have the user always end up seeing the prettified one.

After much to-ing and fro-ing, we came up with the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Prevents browser looping, which does seem
#   to occur in some specific scenarios. Can't
#   explain the mechanics of this problem in
#   detail, but there we go.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Hard-rewrite ("[R]") to "friendly" URL.
# Needs RewriteCond to match original querystring.
# Uses "?" in target to remove original querystring,
#   and "%n" backrefs to move its components.
# Target must be a full path as it's a hard-rewrite.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&cat=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/index/%1/%2/? [L,R]

# Soft-rewrite from "friendly" URL to "real" URL.
# Transparent to browser.
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ /index.php?id=$1&cat=$2
```

Whilst it might seem to be a somewhat strange use case ("*why not just use the proper links in the first place?*", you might ask), just go with it. Regardless of the original requirement, this is the scenario and it's driving me mad.

Without the first rule, the client enters into a request loop, trying to `GET /index/X/Y/` repeatedly and getting `302` each time. The check on `REDIRECT_STATUS` makes everything run smoothly. But I would have thought that after the final rule, no more rules would be served, the client wouldn't make any more requests (note, no `[R]`), and everything would be gravy.

So... why would this result in a request loop when I take out the first rule?

Comment: Not strange usage at all in my opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without being able to tinker with your setup, I can't say for sure, but I believe this problem is due to the following relatively arcane feature of mod_rewrite:

> When you manipulate a URL/filename in per-directory context mod_rewrite first rewrites the filename back to its corresponding URL (which is usually impossible, but see the RewriteBase directive below for the trick to achieve this) and then initiates a new internal sub-request with the new URL. This restarts processing of the API phases.

(source: [mod_rewrite technical documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html), I *highly* recommend reading this)

In other words, when you use a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess` file, it's possible that the new, rewritten URL maps to an entirely different directory on the filesystem, in which case the `.htaccess` file in the original directory wouldn't apply anymore. So whenever a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess` file matches the request, Apache has to restart processing *from scratch* with the modified URL. This means, among other things, that every `RewriteRule` gets checked again.

In your case, what happens is that you access `/index/X/Y/` from the browser. The last rule in your `.htaccess` file triggers, rewriting that to `/index.php?id=X&cat=Y`, so  Apache has to create a new internal subrequest with the URL `/index.php?id=X&cat=Y`. That matches your earlier external redirect rule, so Apache sends a 302 response back to the browser to redirect it to `/index/X/Y/`. But remember, the browser never saw that internal subrequest; as far as it knows, it was already on `/index/X/Y/`. So it looks to you as though you're being redirected from `/index/X/Y/` to that same URL, triggering an infinite loop.

Besides the performance hit, this is probably one of the better reasons that you should avoid putting rewrite rules in `.htaccess` files when possible. If you move these rules to the main server configuration, you won't have this problem because matches on the rules won't trigger internal subrequests. If you don't have access to the main server configuration files, one way you can get around it (*EDIT*: or so I thought, although it doesn't seem to work - see comments) is by adding the `[NS]` (no subrequest) flag to your external redirect rule,

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/index/%1/%2/? [L,R,NS]
```

Once you do that, you should no longer need the first rule that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS`.

Comment: You are, for just one day, my hero and saviour.

Comment: (Though, at first checking, `NS` on either rule doesn't seem to make a difference.)

Comment: Meh, I'll accept it anyway... if nothing else, you provided a great explanation of the most likely cause, which is what I was after. Thanks

Comment: @Tomalak: I thought I'd posted a comment here yesterday but I guess it didn't go through... anyway, Apache is a complicated system, it's hard to understand it all ;-) At times like this I turn to the `RewriteLog`; if you enable that directive, the output in the mod_rewrite log file shows you exactly what each rewrite rule does, and from that it's essentially always possible to figure out what's going on (e.g. why `[NS]` doesn't work). But you do already have a solution that works, so I guess investigating the `[NS]` issue isn't that important.

Comment: @David: I do really want to figure this out; alas, I'm fighting to get any log output.

Comment: http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/mod_rewrite-no-endless-loops looks like it might be describing this issue, but doesn't recommend `[NS]`, instead describing how Apache now implements a maximum number of redirects, rather like I've hacked in with the check for `REDIRECT_STATUS`. Seems like these internal requests are not actually _sub_ -requests.

Comment: @Tomalak: yeah, that's exactly the log output I'm talking about :-) From the excerpt you posted it looks like Apache is in fact not treating the internal redirects as subrequests... maybe that's just the way it works, I forget. The Sitepoint article you linked to is describing something similar, but not quite the same, because there's no external 302 redirect in that example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#rule1
#Guard condition: only if the original client request was for index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&cat=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index/%1/%2/? [L,R]

#rule 2
RewriteRule ^index/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ /index.php?id=$1&cat=$2 [L,NC]
```

**Here is what I think is happening**

From the steps you quoted above

1. Browse to index.php?id=3&cat=5
2. See the location bar read index/3/5/
3. Have the content served from index.php?id=3&cat=5

At Step 1, Rule 1 matches and redirects to location bar and fulfills Step 2.

At Step 3, Rule 2 now matches and rewrites to index.php.

The rules are rerun, for the reasons David stated, but since `THE_REQUEST` is immutable once set to the original request, it still contains `/index/3/5` so Rule 1 does not match.

Rule 2 does not match either and the result of index.php is served.

Most other variables are mutable e.g. `REQUEST_URI`. Their modification during rule processing, and the incorrect expectation that the pattern matches are against the original request is a common reason for infinite loops.

Its feels quite esoteric sometimes, but I am sure there is a logical reason for its complexity :-)

**EDIT**

> Surely there are two distinct requests

There are 2 client requests, the original one from Step1 and the one from the external redirect in step 2.

What I glossed over above is that when Rule 2 matches on the second request, it is rewritten to /index.php and causes an internal redirect. This forces the .htaccess file for `/` directory to be loaded again (it could easily have been another another directory with different .htaccess rules) and Re-run all the rules again.

> So... why would this result in a request loop when I take out the first rule?

When the rules are re-run, the first rule now unexpectedly matches, as a result of Rule2's rewrite, and does a redirect, causing an infinite loop.

David's answer does contain most of this information and is what I meant  "for the reasons David stated".

However, the main point here is that you do need the extra condition, either your condition, which stops further rule processing on internal redirects, or mine, which prevents rule 1 from matching, is necessary to prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: Surely there are two distinct requests