# mod-rewrite recursive loop

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, loops, recursion

I want to change my website's dynamic urls to Search Engine Friendly URL's

Now the urls like this www.website.com/news.php?id=127591 ,
I want it became this www.website.com/news/127591/this-is-article-subject

I added this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

in my .htaccess file. Everything from /news.php?id=123 change to /new/123/this-is-article-subject

**The problem is, now I have two links refer to the same contents. Both /news.php?id=123 and /new/123/this-is-article-subject are the exactly duplicate content**

It is said that search engine will punish this if they found duplicated contents.

I check the answers online and found this,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

HTTP 301 permanent redirect from the old URL to the new URL.

But this still have problem. When I put those three lines together, it not works.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news.php?id=$1 [PT]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

**I guess the reason is the recursive loop. How could I solve this kind of problem?**

Thanks!

---

Update

I changed to this

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

None of the two url work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news.php?id=$1 [L,NS,NE,QSA,NC]
```

#### UPDATE:: Based on your comments:

Inside `news.php` when URL doesn't have `/some-title` then output this META tag to stop indexing `/news/987` type URIs:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Once you notice URI of `/news/987/some-title` inside `news.php` simply mask above META tag.
I have tested it and seems to be working fine so let me know if doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Do I need to Disallow: /news.php in robots.txt to prevent search engine indexing? Like @Jonathan said. If disallow that, i guess will disable both news/123 and news.php?id=123

Comment: robots.txt is for search engines only. In this case since URL redirection is already making to `/news/1234` with R=301, therefore search both will only index that instead of /news.php.

Comment: @anubhava, it seems that google search engine regard /new/123/this-is-article-subject and /new/123 as different links. Actually in my website they are the same links. How to prevent google index /new/123 ?

Comment: @Don: If you see my answer or your accepted answer, both are **NOT** dealing with subject part `some-subject`. My rules are **1)** making an **external redirect** from `/news.php?id=987` to `/news/987` and **2)** making an **internal redirect** from `/news/987` or `/news/987/some-title` to `/news.php?id=987`. Browser will still display `/news/987` OR `/news/987/some-title` and that's why Google is indexing both. Please understand that just using mod_rewrite its not possible to make `/news.php?id=987` into `/news/987/some-title` since `some-title` is no where in the original Query String.

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for help! How could I let search engine know that /news/987 or /news/987/some-title are the same article. Now what i'm doing is in my php code, when the url is something like /news/987, will redirect to /news/987/some-title . But it seems that google search engine still think they are two different urls. I checked google web master tools. It is said that that two links have duplicated title and meta information.

Comment: @Don: Do you still have old type of links on your website like this `<a href="/news.php?id=543">Some News Story</a>` ? Is there any chance of changing those old links to something like: `<a href="/news.php?id=543&title=some-title">Some News Story</a>` If that is the case then a simple modification of .htaccess rules will take care of it otherwise we'll need to investigate other routes.

Comment: @Don: See update section above for another way to prevent duplicate indexing by Google.

Comment: @anubhava: Can I write this part like this? header( 'Location:http://www.example.com/news/'.$id.'/'.urlTitle($article['subject']));echo '<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">';  I want to redirect to the full url if the subject part is not complete. Then tell search engine not index this page. Do you think <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"> can use like this way?

Comment: @Don: I don't think you can attach meta tag in header() call. If I have to do it, I would write above META tag if subject part is not present and via `META refresh tag` do a redirect to the URL with subject. That way Google bot will not index the page without subject part. You may find this Q&A helpful: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/how-to-stop-certain-urls-from-being-indexed

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect the URI in the [HTTP request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1) (i.e. `%{THE_REQUEST}`) as the other could already have been rewritten (like in your case):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /news\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I got 500 Internal Server Error. Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @Don Li: I just forgot to escape the space. Fixed it.

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks for correction! Do I need to Disallow: /news.php in robots.txt to prevent search engine indexing? Like @Jonathan said. If disallow that, i guess will not allow both news/123 and news.php?id=123

Comment: @Don Li: No, the redirection will take care of that.

Comment: @Gumbo: Curious why you have a `?` on the end of the replacement text in the rewrite rule?

Comment: @ridgerunner: The `?` in `/news/%1?` denotes an empty query string and avoids that the originally requested query string is not appended to the replacement as that’s the default if no new query string is specified.

Comment: @Gumbo: Thanks. I see upon closer inspection of the httpd documentation, that this is indeed the correct way to remove an unwanted query string. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about search engines, you could create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file containing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /news.php
```

This will make sure that search engines don't follow the news.php links.

To fix your rewrite rules, you might try adding `L` to the first `RewriteRule` to make sure that mod_rewrite doesn't continue:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news.php?id=$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^news\.php /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not works using this. I got the following message.The page isn't redirecting properly
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
        

        
        

  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.

Answer (score 0):

try using L

```
[L]
```

instead of

```
[PT]
```

Comment: Not works. I got the error message. The page isn't redirecting properly
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
        

        
        

  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If `[L]` doesn't work for you, the issue might be separate internal requests (not sub-requests that you could halt with `[NS]`).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574442/why-does-this-cause-an-infinite-request-loop).

Answer (score 0):

simplest answer just add a canonical link in your head of your html document, this will stop your duplicate content issue.