# How do I go from example.html URL to /example URL?

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, web

How do I go from URL that reads example.com/text.html to one that reads example.com/text?

Edit: Sorry I'm new. The website is coded in HTML and hosted by GoDaddy on a Windows server. I would like to edit this server-side if possible but if not then in individual webpages (with an html snippet)

Comment: You need to be specific about technologies you use.

Comment: What are u talking about.... Is this simple html or any other language.. please specify clearly.

Comment: similar question:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask questions, please put in all the details. Where do you want to use it -- in HTML `<a>` tag, or at the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on what you have - Apache? Then mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
E.g. http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

If you have a Java server, then every framework has freedom to do it on it's own.

Also Ruby, Python, ASP have their own.

Answer (score 0):

add the foillowing line to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hm, that's not much educational :)

Comment: you want me to delete my answer ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a folder named name of file and put index.html's inside.

Sample:

If you want to to make `www.example.com/test.html` to `www.example.com/test` rename **test.html** to **index.html** and put it inside folder **test**

```
Root folder
|
|-->index.html "home page"
|
|
|-->sample page folder 1 "Page 2"
|   |
|   +-->index.html
|
|-->sample page folder 2 "Page 3"
|   |
|   +-->index.html
|
+-->sample page folder 3 "Page 4"
    |
    +-->index.html
```