# How can I configure my website so that the trailing ".html" isn't required in URLs?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

i have created a website in a software I own. The software uploads the site through an FTP server. For some reason, all the pages have `.html` at the end. My problem is if the user says `www.mydomain.com/live` instead of `www.mydomain.com/live.html`, they get a 404 error. How do I fix this to where they do not have to add `.html` at the end of the pages?

Comment: What web server are you running (IIS, Apache, etc.)?

Comment: i am not sure...i am using bluehost's FTP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: so, how do i add this to my site...

Comment: Just [create a `.htaccess` file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: sorry, but how. I am 16 and have absolutly never heard of that type of file...

Comment: Tiwo very kindly linked to the documentation. It's right there in the first paragraph under What they are/How to use them.

Comment: ha, wow i did not even see the link

Comment: so, do i just upload it to my ftp...the file?

Comment: The documentation explains that, @Elite, in the *What they are/How to use them* section. You are running Apache, right?

Comment: What do you mean....i am using bluehost's FTP server

Comment: In the end, .html files are hosted (almost always) by an HTTP server, also known as a web server. Bluehost uses Apache, which supports .htaccess files, so that's good.

Comment: ok, thanks...also, why are people trying to close my question...i have found everyone's answers helpful!

Comment: @EliteGamer Your question is being voted as an Exact Duplicate of the countless other "how do you make a url without an extension"-type questions.

Comment: Also, technically, this isn't an on-topic question on Stack Overflow. There are [better sites for this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but **DON'T ASK THERE**. There are hundreds of dupes of this question. Just search for .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is this: put the content into `live/index.html`. Then, requests to `/live` are usually redirected to `/live/`, which is then served from `live/index.html`.