# Is there an alternative to .htaccess for GitHub Pages?

Tags: .htaccess, github, github-pages

I understand that `.htaccess` [is not supported](http://rawsyntax.com/blog/blogging-on-jekyll-url-redirects/) by GitHub Pages. Is there an alternative for password-protecting particular directories for websites hosted by GitHub Pages?

Comment: but the directories are open source unless its in a private repo?

Comment: you're right about that... but assuming one has a private repo...

Comment: yeah... they should add a similar function to .htaccess

Comment: The exact same question has been asked ok Webapps.stackexchange:
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35692/8562

Comment: @MartinThoma probably 'cause he asked it.

Comment: You can use something like this to create a hidden directory https://github.com/matteobrusa/Password-protection-for-static-pages

Answer (score 16):

Although you can't use `.htaccess` or `.conf`, <strike>Github has instructions on how to use</strike> the Jekyll Redirect From plugin.

<strike>https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/</strike>

The page above no longer has any mention of the plugin. The direct link to the jekyll-redirect-from plugin GitHub repo is https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

Comment: Does this plugin allow for external redirects? 
In my `.htaccess ` I had `Redirect /PDF https://drive.google.com/file/d//view?usp=sharing`

Answer (score 11):

"Unfortunately, GitHub pages only supports static pages. There is no way to make it execute server-side code and thus it's impossible to protect your pages with any kind of authentication scheme. If you expand further on why you need to password-protect your pages, maybe I can help you find a workaround."

Source: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35692/is-there-an-alternative-to-using-htaccess-to-password-protect-subdirectories-in

Comment: I am here since I needed a git hub page to redirect based on the google API not liking Angular App hashtag URL. Now since I cant control the redirect I will need to host the App myself - unless I can get around the Google Console API somehow...

Answer (score 6):

This post comes out at the top of web search when you look for `.htaccess` redirects in github pages. I am going to answer this question in that sense.

One option is to use a DNS redirect instead. You do this by putting a file named `CNAME` in the project's root directory (not sure if it works in a subdirectory). Just put the redirection URL in the file. However, there are a few limitations, e.g. you can only redirect to a website's root.

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: @Atais, you can use DNS CNAME / DNS Synthetic records to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a `404.html` to redirect users from old S9Y index.php to my new blog on Github Pages. Check this commit: https://github.com/lionello/lionello.github.io/commit/c175f6524a53e29aea1890c8a758afd0e8944852

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes you can now add "404.html" in you code Repository. You can display a custom 404 error page when people try to access nonexistent pages on your github site.

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site)!