# Apache redirect keeping URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm making a JavaScript web app running on an Apache 2 server. I'm wondering if it's possible (either with mod_rewrite or some other mod) to make any path you type load the index.html from the root path, but keeping the URL?

For example: "example.com/blah/blegh" will load "example.com/index.html", but the address bar will still have "example.com/blah/blegh". Same if you tried typing "example.com/everything/is/index" would still load "example.com/index.html" and have "example.com/everything/is/index" in the address bar.

A simple answer about any mods I would need to use and which commands might be best would suffice. Though a code example would be very useful since I'm new to regex's and Apache rewriting.

Thank you for your time :)

Note: I'm doing this since I'm using [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) to parse URLs/titles into the  address bar and tab titles while navigating (a one-page dynamic site). I'd like to be able to just load up the root index.html with the user's initial URL request and respond to users' actions that way much like a REST server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you want to rewrite without redirecting. This requires enabling mod_proxy and mod_rewrite in Apache's httpd.conf.

Then, the rewrite should look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [NC,L,QSA]
```

Reference:

- [What exactly does the Multiviews options in .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess)
- [htaccess rewrite without redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452907/htaccess-rewrite-without-redirect)
- [Apache: RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)