# How can I remove file path and .html extension from my URL?

Tags: html, .htaccess

One of the pages on my website is: https://bojanstavrikj.github.io/content/articles/wunderground_scraper_original/wunderground_scraper.html

I started keeping my articles in separate folders. Obviously, once I changed that the whole path is appearing in the browser when opening the article.

What I want is to rewrite this URL as: https://bojanstavrikj.github.io/content/wunderground_scraper

As I understand this can be done with htaccess, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Is .htaccess supported on github.io?

Comment: Looks like you need to use Jekyll. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446435/is-there-an-alternative-to-htaccess-for-github-pages

Comment: If the files are stored in seperate directories, could they just not be labelled as "index.html" within their respective folders, rather than a .htaccess rule? Or is there something I'm missing here?