# How to link to pages without the .html extension?

Tags: html

I would like to link to pages inside my website, e.g:
Not: mywebsite.com/about.html But: mywebsite.com/about/

I've seen various websites doing this but it looks like they also react differently to things:

Apple.com:
apple.com/iphone/ works, apple.com/iphone/index.html works, apple.com/iphone redirects.

Opera.com:
opera.com/mobile/ redirects, opera.com/mobile works, opera.com/mobile.html does **not** work.

Mozilla.com:
mozilla.org/en-US/ works, mozilla.org/en-US redirects, mozilla.org/en-US/index.html does **not** work.

Which leads to another question: Are there different methods for this?

**Edit:**
It seems that Apple uses a folder for every page, e.g. a folder called 'iphone' with an index.html file inside it?
But Opera and Mozilla use something in the .htaccess file?

Comment: It's called URL rewriting... now this is your starting point, go and read :-)

Answer (score 20):

Removing Extensions

To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.php to yoursite.com/wallpaper you have to add the following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper you simply have to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

That’s it! You can now link pages inside the HTML document without needing to add the extension of the page. For example:

```
 <a href="http://whatever.com/wallpaper" title="wallpaper">wallpaper</a>
```

Comment: Tried this it now says "Could not connect" any ideas why?

Answer (score 12):

They are using `.htaccess` and `URL rewriting`. This is part of server configuration. You can not do it with html only.

This [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) explains basics of URL rewriting.

Comment: Is URL rewriting in the .htaccess file? And do they all use different .htaccess and/or URL rewriting things?

Comment: Yes. You can define alising rules in your .htaccess. There are many websites dealing on this. Look at @Marijke's good example.

Answer (score 9):

You folder then has to contain a file: `index.*`.
Like: /iphone/index.html, which can be /iphone/ as well

Or work with `.htaccess`

Comment: What is better to use? Is one faster than the other or more stable?

Comment: depends on the purpose. If you want your site to be addressed via foo.com/folder/ you might want to use `index.*`, because it is much easier and less elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

In the .htaccess file in your sites root folder just add the following line:

```
# ---- Render pages without urls
Options +MultiViews
```

Comment: i'm using cpanel and this is the most simplest solution in 2022

Answer (score 2):

[The most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963457/2652785) doesn't check whether the URL points to a directory, so you're going to get some mysterious 'not found' errors when it tries to append '.html' to a directory path. Easily fixed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

The first condition will only pass if the path does *not* point to a valid directory. The second will only pass if the path points to a valid file when the .html extension is added. If *both* conditions pass, the rewrite rule simply adds ‘.html’ to the filename.

Notice that we can just match the entire path with `.*`. You can reject paths that contain a period character if you wish, but it's not really necessary since you've already checked that `{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html` is a valid file. In any case, it is unnecessary to escape a period character when it's inside a character class. I know you see this `[^\.]` everywhere, but the slash is redundant. `[^.]` is how to write it and look like a regex pro.

This kind of redirect will be invisible to the user because, by default, mod_rewrite does the substitution internally, without informing the browser. If you wanted to do a permanent redirect, you would add the [R=301] flag at the end.

---

Alternatively, as Genus Amar said, you can just enable the *Multiviews* option on a per-directory basis by adding this [Options Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) to the .htaccess file:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

It's worth adding that this will only work if the server administrator has enabled MultiViews with the [AllowOverride Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride), and it won't allow you to perform additional redirects.

---

Neither of these solutions (on their own) will remove the `.html` if it’s part of the requested URL. If you want to do that as well, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63803841/2652785) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5730092/2652785).

Comment: I checked many websites, and only this one worked for me perfectly. Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

Let the website be [www.abc.com/index.html](http://www.abc.com/index.html) and you have to display only  [www.abc.com/index](http://www.abc.com/index)  then in node js (express) it will be

```js
//Let your all files like index.html, css, js be in public folder

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')




app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
  var filePath = ""
  const fileName = req.params.name;

//////Check if file is not .html file like css, js etc
  if(fileName.includes(".css") || fileName.includes(".js") || fileName.includes(".png") || fileName.includes(".jpg") || fileName.includes(".svg")){
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', fileName)
  }
  else{
  filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', fileName + ".html");
  }
  res.sendFile(filePath, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error sending file: ${err.message}`);
      res.status(err.status).end();
    } else {
      console.log(`File sent: ${filePath}`);
    }
  });
});

// serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score -4):

Make your href attribute equal to the page you want to link or .. If you need to
move up a directory.

Ex: href="contact.html"
Ex: href="../links/contact.html"

Comment: This is the exact problem we are trying to solve.