# Show correct URL without extension & redirect if URL is incorrect

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've added a **bounty of 50** to this question. I'm trying to make it so that:

1. all website pages show www.example.com/page/ - instead of /page. My current code below is only successful for www.example.com/page

How can the .htaccess code be corrected to achieve this?

Also, changing the canonical URL meta tags from www.mysite.com/page to www.example.com/page/ - will www.example.com/page/ show up in search engines instead of /page ?

The current .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Note that the first rewriting conditions just forward to www. and https, so the only part that might need editing might just be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

So all I want to do it simply add a '/'. A wordpress blog (presumably PHP files rather than HTML) that achieves my wants on the same website (it's at www.example.com/blog/) has htaccess code being:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I'm not sure how this works but I'd love to learn more about .htaccess and redirects, but nothing much seems to be on the web for beginners. I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919526/how-to-link-to-pages-without-the-html-extension) post. It also must be https (not sure why but blog posts also can have a http link, whereas other pages redirect to https).

The website also has a blog (php files) on it with its own htaccess file, installed under example.com/blog/ - the htaccess code is the default wordpress one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your .htaccess as this in site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# remove .php or .html extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.(?:html|php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# add .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

# add .html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

For issues with relative paths for css/js/images add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: that very nearly solved the problem, thanks, but now the css stylesheet and js scripts won't load because, when I click them in inspector, they show .html .html .html .html .html .html .html .html too many times. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: something else I should probably mention is currently the pages are all .html, but I want them to show as / without the .html extension, because I might also change the pages to .php - (and it wouldn't matter if the extension is just / )

Comment: Check my updated answer and also a note on `<base ..>` tag.

Comment: wow thanks that's very interesting! I added that code to my site and it worked. I put the base / on one page, and it worked as expected, but clicking to other pages sometimes caused problems and the site crashed often - was this because I didn't add the base tag to the other pages? Also, there is a blog on the site with its own htaccess file, and now the blog is not working (I've edited my answer with this blog htaccess code). How can this be changed to fix? I will accept your answer and award you the 50 bounty when I see your next reply. and thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes you need to add `<base ..>` tag in all of your pages to make it work otherwise css/js etc won't be loaded (due to your use of relative links across the site).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164125/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user8758206).

Comment: @anubhava Why 2x  '\s' in : '# remove .php or .html extensions' ?
BTW : Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, the top one is excluding .php from the URL and the bottom one excludes .html from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation to your code. Code-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work for me. it only does the same as my code. It doesn't display example.com/page/, instead it displays example.com/page - also it doesn't redirect from .html to / or from page to page/