# How to create a formatless webpage?

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, format

I saw many websites with many webpages(apart from home page) with no format like http://www.apple.com/ios/

It has no format like it is not http://www.apple.com/ios.html or anything.

Even this page is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
It has no extensions!!!

How do i create that??

I have my site in which I want mysite/login.aspx to appear as mysite/login
Also mysite/welcome.html as mysite/welcome

Can anyone out there help me?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you Google this you will find your answer.

Comment: look into htaccess and mod rewrite

Comment: Try sreaching: URL rewriting

Comment: Well, technically, the `ios` link *does* have a `.html` extension, just not the way you accessed it. See http://www.apple.com/ios/index.html. Most servers will server `index.html` when accessing a directory (eg, `/ios/`).

Comment: @KennyThompson - this is a little misleading, I help maintain many websites, none of them built on an MVC framework, all of them using `.htaccess` for URL rewriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually done in the .htaccess file in Apache.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

a-la [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you name your file index.html (or index.php etc) and upload it to mydomain.com/test/index.html, it will be available at mydomain.com/test/

Other than that, use url rewriting via a htaccess file. 
Here's [a good tutorial](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file. Do not make your own but download your current file from your FTP server, change it and then upload and overwrite your old one.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^securemyhome\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.securemyhome.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

 # 3 ---- Make pages render without their extension in the url
 Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

For IIS webserver,

install to IIS the "Url Rewrite" Module,  "add rule" and follow the wizard.

[download Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

[About Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)