# Remove .html and .php extensions with .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I remove the file type from my webpages without creating a new directory and naming the file index.php. I want http://example.com/google.html to http://example.com/google.

How would I go about doing this.

PS: I tried looking at some other tutorials but there to confusing. I do now that it can be done in .htaccess

Comment: @MarcB Yes, Im aware. However i tryed that and it dosent work. Plus i need to rename all my files.

Comment: If you want to learn how to remove `php` and `html` extensions from URLs using htaccess ,  You can try this link https://helponnet.com/2020/02/04/remove-html-and-php-extension-with-htaccess-rewriterule-url-rewriting-tips/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, I know that this question was asked multiple times already and is answered, but I will give a little more comprehensive answer based on my experience.

Here is the .htaccess code snippet that will help you:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

I want to stress some important things here for everybody's reference:

- **This code snippet doesn't remove entry scripts from url (such as
  `index.php` used by many PHP frameworks)**
- **It only removes `.php` extension, if you want to remove other extension as well (e.g. `.html`), copy and paste 3rd block and replace `php` with other extension.**
- **Don't forget to also remove extension from anchors (links) href.**

Comment: @SimplePi Than I will suggest you accept the answer and mark it, so that this question doesn't show up in unanswered ones. If you have any problems, let me know, so that I could help you further with this.

Comment: Yep, Just had to wait a few minutes before i accepted it due to restrictions.

Answer (score 18):

@armanP's accepted answer above does not `remove` .php extension from php urls. It just makes it possible to access php files without using `.php` at the end. For example `/file.php` can be accessed using `/file` or `/file.php` but this way you have 2 diffrent urls pointing to the same location.

If you want to remove `.php`  completely, you can use the following  rules in `/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on 
#redirect /file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
# now we will internally map /file to /file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php  [L]
```

To remove **.html** ,use this

```
 RewriteEngine on
 #redirect /file.html to /file
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.html [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
 # now we will internally map /file to/ file.html
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.html  [L]
```

Solution for Apache 2.4* users :

If your apache version is 2.4 ,you can use the Code without `RewriteConditions` On Apache 2.4  we can  use `END` flag instead of the `RewriteCond` to prevent Infinite loop error.

Here is a solution for Apache 2.4 users

```
 RewriteEngine on

 #redirect  /file.php to /file
  RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [L,R]
 # now we will internally map /file to /file.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Note  : If your external stylesheet or images 
aren't loading after adding these rules ,to fix this you can either make your links absolute changing `<img src="foo.png>` to `<img src="/foo.png>` .Notice the `/` before the filename . or change the URI base add the following to head section of your Web page `<base href="/">` .

Your Webpage fails to load css and js due to the following reason :

When your browser  url  changes from `/file.php` to `/file` server thinks that `/file` is a directory and it tries to append that in front of all relative paths . For example : when your url is `http://example.com/file/` your relative path changes to `<img src "/file/foo.png">` thus the image fails to load . You can use one of the solutions I mentioned in the last peragraph to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Amit, your answer is solved my problem. I'm using NuxtJS and somehow htaccess doesn't work I expected. But your answer is best solution to remove php and html extensions from url. So my router is working perfectly now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that this seems to conflict with "ErrorDocument 404 /404.php" which is commonly used to set a custom 404 page. The problem is that the 404 page now returns a 200 status code which is interpreted as a soft 404. To fix this, you need to add "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404" as the first rewrite condition before both rewrite rules here so that neither of these rules will run for the 404 page. This solves the issue I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for the internal path when removing .php (using code above as a reference).

```
# Start of Apache Rewrite Rules

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase
  
# From http:// to https://
  
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
  
# Redirect /file.php to /file with POST (enabled)

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST     
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]

# Add trailing slash to url

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]

# Remove .php-extension from url

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

 </IfModule>

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
```

**Note:**

Above is the code for accepting URL without **.php**, URL with **.php** will be transformed without **.php** (.php will be removed) all files/folders with their respective path will open normally without any issue, also post & get method will work just fine.