# Changing html website urls

Tags: html, url

When I load my website the first page that is shown is **www.website.com/index.html**. This is what you can see in your adressbar. When I open a second page on the website **www.website.com/page1.html** is shown.

Now how can I change **www.website.com/index.html** to **www.website.com/** and the other pages just to **www.website.com/page1** instead of **www.website.com/page1.html**

Comment: You need to provide information about which environment your website is hosted within. Without this information it will hard for anyone to answer.

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617605/3168859)..might help you provided you are running under Apache server..

Comment: Just a guess but you'd probably want to reference your API for the URL instead of going to index.html, first. But, if you're wanting to take the .html off of the url then you can just manipulate the appSettings.Url (as a string) to take off the .html

Comment: @Lal That's assuming the OP is running under Apache. This isn't hinted at in the question.

Comment: ya..i just edited my comment..@lee

Answer (score 0):

I assume the website uses only plain html. If so, you can create another folder called `page1` and inside create an `index.html`. This way you will be able to access the new index.html (the one inside `page1` folder) just by pointing your browser to:

```
www.website.com/page1/
```

This works if the website is hosted on a server like Apache.

Other option is to redirect the request. Please have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: @Lal Yes. That's why I assumed is plain html. We don't even know if his server is Apache.

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
      if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
      </script>
```

**Note : where / is the path u want to show.**

### OR

you have to add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

it shows the url like `mysite.com`   no matter which link i have clicked. but i have a problem with this code while reloading the page the complete url with query string blink into address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I do that works because .htaccess files have always caused me issues.

Step 1: Create a folder with what you want to be shown in the browser (website.com/foldername)

Step 2: Put a index.html inside of that folder

Step 3: Change your pages links and linked files to work with the folders (../foldername/index.html)

Comment: How do you know the OP is running Apache?