# .htaccess redirect sub domain

Tags: php, apache, dns, server

I tired to redirecting my subdomain to the another main domain on one hosting. But i had error looks like the php not working.

Can someone help me?

This my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php55” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php55 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^the\.host\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.the\.host\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/doc\.newhost\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

and then this is my /var/log/apache2/error_log

```
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758085 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: 2894083 already exist.: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758097 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: ID exists..: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758104 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: 2894083: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758122 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: LAND in Riverstone 27 Lots R2: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758277 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: 3138523 already exist.: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758289 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: ID exists..: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758300 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: 3138523: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758319 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: DEVELOPMENT OPPORTUNITY: GOLD COAST: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758458 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: 3031246 already exist.: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:14:36.758472 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 9610] [client 54.79.10.85:46556] AH01215: ID exists..: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
[Mon Mar 06 05:20:03.673775 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 11836] [client 46.101.110.32:44194] AH01215: PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for plugin_dir_url(), called in /home/platformsoftware/public_html/wp-content/themes/horseexchange/inc/plugins_modify.php on line 41 and defined in /home/platformsoftware/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 723: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php55
```

Can someone tell me how it happen? and how to i fix it. FYI i already change permission file to 777 and change file ownership on my server.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542588/remove-php-from-url/42401685#42401685