# Magento .htaccess rule for specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have a multidomain magento setup, Says **abc.com** and **xyz.com** .

I want to write a redirect rule for **xyz.com** only in the root **.htaccess** file. When i write a rule what it does, it redirects all urls from **abc.com** also to **xyz.com and 404**.

Basically i need to redirect all **.html url's from xyz.com** only to without .html .
I am using :

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.xyz.com$1
```

Comment: I want for example  xyz.com/categoryurl.html redirect to xyz.com/categoryurl (.html to without html for all urls on xyz.com only. It shouldnot affect abc.com which is configured on same magento instance)

Comment: to remove .html at the end of the url in xyz.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that **.html** at the end of the url by following below steps

```
System -> configuration -> catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations
```

Here you can find 2 attributes named as **"Product URL Suffix" and "Category URL Suffix"**. Just ***empty*** those fields in XYZ.com store

[image]

**EDIT**

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* http://urdomain/html/%1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]
   </IfModule>
```

refer this following url,

[How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

here you can get the solutions

**UPDATE**

I'm Not sure. But I hope, It may help you

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xyz[NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I donot want to remove .html from url but only redirect .html to without .html as all urls are already cached in google with .html

Comment: Also issue is that the "Product URL Suffix" and "Category URL Suffix" is setup with ".html" for all stores but for xyz.com  in frontend the urls are showing without .html and if i open any url with .html(from google searches) it gives 404. So approx 5000 google cached urls with .html giving 404. I want to redirect them to without .html to avoid 404.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didnot found my answer there. But you can see in  my question itself , i have the solution but the issue is that my Magento is mulidomain. Applying that rule applies for all domains. I want that the rule only should apply to xyz.com.

Comment: don't you have separate .htaccess for both domains?

Comment: No there is only one htaccess as there is one magento installation.

Comment: You must create another .htacccess file for that store and map that domain with this .htaccess file