# How to stop .html showing up in the url?

Tags: html

This is probably a really simple fix, but how do I set it so when you go to my site (www.skidsfordays.com) it jsut comes up as that and not www.skidsfordays.com/index.html and then every page on the site has .html after it. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The normal behavior for an index page is that .html or .php is **not** written in the url. Are you using a .htaccess?

Comment: You could end this mayhem with the .htaccess, as @Xatenev has suggested. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: you have to put `index.html` along with remaining pages and redirect your homepage to `index.html`

Comment: @CoderMusgrove He doesn't even need rewrite for the behaviour he wants. **Options +Multiviews** would probably be enough already. [at]nawazlj No sense what you mean?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a .htaccess in your web root directory and add the following line into it:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

-> Done.

This means, that the server does not require the file extension (for example: .html, .php ) to load the requested file.

Answer (score 0):

To hide index.html please Add below code in below code in your **.htaccess** file here we rewrite the index.html url to your site domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$
RewriteRule (.*?)(index\.html)?$ http://yoursite.com$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

To hide .html Extension please try below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```