# How to remove .html when someone visit your static website

Tags: html, nginx

Right now I have a static website that is served by nginx. 
Example page: www.mydomain.com

If I or anyone visits www.mydomain.com, it shows as www.mydomain.com/index.html.

How can I prevent the trailing .html and end up with www.mydomain.com/index showing up instead?

I can find many questions talking about similar issues but none of the proposed solutions worked.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop .html showing up in the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487034/how-to-stop-html-showing-up-in-the-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the `www.yourdomain.com/index.html` to just `www.yourdomain.com` using the .htaccess file

[Here is a guide to redirect and rewrite URLs using .htacess](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Comment: That is different from what I want to accomplish. Another example: want to change www.mydomain.com/about.html to www.mydomain.com/about. I tried the .htaccess by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the index.html and the .html is something different.

For the index.html you need a "redirect" in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# redirect html pages to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```

Now, for the .html is not working the same way. If you add the below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?about/?$ about.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/?otherlink/?$ otherlink.html [L]
```

then when you visit  www.mydomain.com/about it will "read" the  www.mydomain.com/about.html . So you need to add the above in your htaccess file. Check that is working (by just typing the URL ) and then change all your links to the one without the file extension.

Comment: htaccess is only for Apache server. Not for Nginx.