# Subpages names how to change

Tags: html, web

I want to ask you guys, how to change subpages names? Like when I created my website first page is index.html (when I wrote it in taskbar and enter this website it shows www.example) next is gallery.html but when I go to gallery it show www.example/gallery.html and I want to be like this www.example/gallery without .html or even www.example/g.  Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Well, it depends a lot of the time. Are you hosting it locally or on a server?

Comment: Yes I have it on server right now

Comment: @Mikik here you go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: Thanks ! I was not sure where to find it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `.htaccess` code. Rewrites `www.myweb.com/test.php` to `www.myweb.com/test`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: If you can rewrite `test.html` to `/test`. Edit all `.php` in my code to `.html`. Accept my answer if I help :)

Comment: Ok. Will do in few minutes