# How to prevent having: www.examplesite.com/INDEX.HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, web

The topic sounds stupid but I've noticed some websited have like "examplepage.com/posts/" Without a file extension. I know that if you use wordpress you get it like that but I also know websites that dosn't use wordpress and have it like that. How do I get that and is it hard to get? Thank you! :)

Comment: it's known as a mod rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `.htaccess` file in your root directory and have to make some rules in it refer to this link for help: [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url).

`.htaccess` is the files i.e. used for URL rewriting and with this you can manage almost all types of URL manipulations

Comment: I see that the top-rated answer there sais to link it like this
"<a href="http://www.example.com/page">page</a>"
But the file can be called "page.html" right?

Comment: That would also require the `.htaccess` configurations. Please dig in further to `.htacess`, you will get your query solved.

Comment: Alright, thank you! :) I will have a look at it

Comment: Pleasure...and please approve the answer if it helped you :-) .