# I attempted to remove the .html extension from my pages and now when clicked, navigation goes to another site

Tags: html, .htaccess

*This question is unique because I do not need to remove the .html from the file extensions; I need to have internal links function correctly.

My site is http://purplerosecare.com and I tried creating a .htaccess page with the suggested copy/paste from the SO page: [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

The code I used is below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.proofers.co.uk/new} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.proofers.co.uk/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(The code & .htaccess have both been removed)

The problem I'm facing is whenever I click on a link in the navigation it sends me to http://www.proofers.co.uk/new/. How can I get the site functional again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: I reviewed that one before (might even be the link I referred to in the post) but it is two separate issues.

Comment: No - it's only one issue. The code you have copied does exactly what one would expect, which you'd understand if you read it. Other answers on the linked question _do_ cover what you need.

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand. Since you have a grasp on the idea, mind sharing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you even have that URI in your `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess file

```
#Remove html extensions from files
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```