# How to make redirecting page like http://lorem.com/contact for contact.html?

Tags: html, redirect

I was trying to make a redirect address like **http://lorem.com/contact/** for *contact.html* file,which is in root folder. Is there any tool or file to do this?

I had tried renaming *contact.html* into *index.html*, and then put it unde **/contact** folder. It worked, as a address **http://lorem.com/contact/**, but I think this is not a proper way to do.

(Note: Title might be weird, for not knowing what keywords to describe this. Any help of editing is appreciated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With .htaccess under apache you can do the redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

As for removing of .html from the url, simply link to the page without .html

[page](http://www.example.com/page)

Source: [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)