# 301 redirect does not match directory structure

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have website with 3000 pages in HTML. Now I have migrated to CMS which does not have any extension in URL. I kept the same structure of URL as I had in HTML site.

For Example:

HTML site URL :

```
www.site.com/xyzdirectory/abc.html
```

CMS site

```
www.site.com/xyzdirectory/abc
```

For that, I am using below `.htaccess` code.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com$1
```

But It does not match directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the .html extension from a html file for example :

```
www.site.com/xyzdirectory/abc.html
```

to

```
 www.site.com/xyzdirectory/abc
```

you simply have to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Refer [this](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) SO post for more

Comment: I have moved from simple HTML site to Concrete5 CMS. Will it still work ?
There are around 3000 pages and 25 directories. Will it match same structure without .html ? I mean redirect.

Comment: What could be the rule , if my site is in subdirectory and this rule only applies to subdirectory  ?
e.g. www.mainsite.com/demosite

Comment: I mean I have another site in root directory, where I don't want to apply this rule. This rule only work for the sub directory , where I have demo site,

Comment: you can do something..create a subdirectory and place htaccess codes within them and give it a try ! Do not try them directly to your files if you are so much worried about.Just try it out and if confident just go ahead with target subdirectory !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83384/discussion-between-user3288891-and-utility).