# Remove .html from url with .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

Im trying to remove the .html from the url so that www.example.com/page.html would be www.example.com/page.
I tried using .htaccess with this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My html code is simply : `<a href = "page">link</a>`

This didn't work as every time I click on the link, an error page shows up

Comment: This Q&A should help. [Remove HTML extension from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: I found the right answer on that page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add and not remove .html (rewrite `page` to `page.html`)
You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on - [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url). This was the only .htaccess script that worked:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.proofers.co.uk/new} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.proofers.co.uk/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```