# Remove .html from URL + redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to remove the .html part from the URL's that are shown in the URL.

I was able to fix that with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
```

That works! :)

But now I got double URL's of every page

- page1
- page1.html
- etc.

I don't want a 404-error on the .html pages so I would like to redirect this to the page without .html (301-redirect). But i have no idea to do that in the .htaccess

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But doesn't work --> .html files are still working

Anybody that could help me? :)
Thanks!

ps. I really can't write .htaccess, please answer that I could copy-paste. That's a lot!

Comment: What happens exactly? What isn't as you'd want it?

Comment: Look at the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11813084/1741542

Comment: This answer also looks good http://stackoverflow.com/a/34726322/1741542

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```