# HTML and HTAccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have been struggling with this all morning and I have not had much luck.

I am trying to get the following stackoverflow post to work: [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Here is my file directory with the htaccess file:
[image]

Here is my code that works fine using .html
[image]

So I went into sublime text and posted the same code into a .htaccess file as shown here (also in my directory first pic):
[image]

I then changed my links and removed .html
[image]

But I get an error [image]

If anyone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful! Been bashing my head on this all morning

Comment: Consider if you simply want a text-based website, check out Sculpin or Jekyll, which output to flat files. You can also host your site on Github. There are other server technologies out there too, like nginx and lighthttpd (couple others I can't recall). I would recommend looking into the hobby versions of Heroku, Digital Ocean or Azure if you have a minimum comprehension of using git; they really nearly abstract the server out of the equation. Also look into docker-compose, and stay away from WAMP/XAMPP/MAMP. Please for the love of donuts don't serve a site to the world off your computer.

Comment: Hi Jared Farrish, this is all hosted on my personal github page. I uploaded pics from my local server only for the stack overflow post. On my github though the links go to index.html, resume.html, etc.. which is the reason I tried to find a solution

Comment: Local development, that's how it works; look into docker-compose, very easy to get something going (instead of *AMP stuff, which is long in the tooth technique). Don't run it for the world there, though; then deploy to a cloud-based provider on the cheap using git. Heroku's [Getting Started with PHP](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) is a pretty good intro. Just saying, give it a shot.

Comment: Rewriting urls is a feature of the server system you're using, whether it's Apache or nginx or Tomcat. That's really just detail.

Comment: https://store.docker.com/images/php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a file used to control access for [Apache web servers](https://httpd.apache.org/). It won't affect anything unless you're running and accessing an Apache server. From your screenshots I can see that you're directly opening a file from your hard drive.

Your browser is saying `File not found` because you're trying to access a non-existent file. The address bar in your browser should say this:

```
file:///Users/mikegeng/Documents/GitHub/MichaelGeng.github.io/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you Clonkex. I feel pretty dumb now. It says File not Found because I renamed it to "<a href="index" ... instead of "<a href="index.html". I am curious if htere is another way to remove the .html without using apache web servers? If not, I will go ahead and start configuring a web server since I would like the links to show up on my personal website as /index instead of /index.html. Kind Regards.

Comment: @MMM Aha no worries, and definitely no need to feel dumb, it's super hard to work this stuff out as a beginner. I know from experience :P

Comment: @MMM Well as far as I'm aware, there is no way. The reason is that the browser is directly accessing the file, and there's no way to tell it that `index` is the same as `index.html`.

Comment: Yea, it's quite a lot to learn and I just started this morning since a personal website is going to be my side project this summer (I do C++ development at an internship). Would you recommend me installing apache web servers? For reference, this is for my personal website on github

Comment: @MMM Well if you're planning on hosting your website from your computer (and you want it to be accessible from over the internet) you'll need to be aware of port forwarding and all that confusing stuff. There's plenty of cheap free webhosting solutions where you can just upload your files and then it's easy to access them. But if you do want to host it yourself, Apache is a good solution. It's pretty easy to get going out of the box too. Just drop your files in `www-data`, if I remember correctly, and then run the server. For testing, miniweb is a great little minimalistic server.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much Clonkex! I will look into hosting this website through Apache :)

Comment: @MMM No worries at all, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` is used by [Apache Webserver](https://httpd.apache.org/). You must install and configure an Apache Webserver and access your site through `http://localhost` for example.

Currently your `.htaccess` is completely ignored until your site is served by Apache.