# How to get a forwards slash url?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a website with 000webhost, and I was wondering how I can get a url like this: `Website.com/ITCMDN` to forward to `Website.com/ITCMDN.html` Like I don't want people to have to type in the `.html` part, and I know this must be possible. Should I put something in my Index.html? Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to see with PHP nor HTML, it depends on you web server

Comment: I think its PHP 5

Comment: @gogaz routing can and does happen in php too. Indeed, it's possible to do from the server, but php side routing allows for much more liberty.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: gives me error 404, and even though ITCMDN.Html exists, its now not letting me open that either (www.Website.com/ITCMDN.html)

Comment: @MarkDodsons Apologies. Please try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url for other answers

Comment: I figured it out here: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/remove-html-extension-not-working/101235