# Problems removing html extensions from https:// 123-reg hosting htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

It's the first time I've used 123-reg for website hosting (I usually use another host). The site has an SSL certificate and the htaccess file redirects to https:// HOWEVER... it's not removing the html extensions from the pages (it DID remove them when it was http:// )

123-reg say it's something I'm doing or not doing at my end, but the following htaccess code works just fine with my other host, just not 123-reg.

htaccess code I'm using (which also directs to https:// )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Here's the website url: https://buyrich.co.uk/

Comment: What error do you get when you go to an html file without. html extension at the end?

Comment: I don't get an error code if I remove the html extension manually but as soon as I click onto another page, the html extension re-appears

Comment: The rule you are using doesn't remove `.html` extension. It just makes it so that you can access your html files even without `.html` . If you want to remove .html extension completely from your urls ,see the following  post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: I checked out that post and added the following code to the htaccess file but that isn't working either? Do I need to change the http to https in the following?

RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* http://localhost/html/%1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it with this code from that post, thank you:

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
```

RewriteCond 
     RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```