# How to remove .html extension in URL on google cloud platform (storage bucket) hosted site?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a site hosted on the Google Cloud Platform, specifically a static site in a storage bucket not in App Engine or Compute Engine. How would I go about removing the .html that appears at the end of a URL?

I've tried uploading a .htaccess file with [methods described online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) but that doesn't seem to work on GCP or am I missing something?