# replacing ".html" inside a href with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I have a wordpress site with lots of links in it. Every link has the extension ".html" (like `<a href="https://example.com/about.html>`).

I like to add a filter which searches for the ".html" and replaces it with "" (`<a href="https://example.com/about>`) on all pages.

I have tried to get this done with str_ireplace and the gettext filter.

```
function kb_rename_links( $kb_rename_item ) 
{  
$kb_rename_item = str_ireplace( '.html', '', $kb_rename_item );

return $kb_rename_item;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'kb_rename_links' );
```

This snipped doesn't do the job (it works for plain text). I think the gettext filter isn't the right one for this job or even i need a action here. But i am to noobish to find the right one.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to modify the `.htaccess` file to remove the .html extensions. This way you don't have to touch the code at all.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

[source](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Edit: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) is a similar stackoverflow post to my solution.

Comment: yes, i use this workaround now but i don't like this solution cause i also like to change an string inside an .img tag as soon as i find a solution. T

Answer (score 0):

Try 'the_content' filter instead ot gettext

Comment: forgot to say that the links are part of hardcoded page template. Content is empty actually.

Comment: If so Why don't search and replace in template files?