# Apache server taking me to wrong URL but only for one link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

The problem is quite confusing and I haven't been able to find a solution for this, I tried clearing caches, deleting HTACCESS file, still doesn't work.

I am using WAMP, and my project's homepage is in a directory, so the URL structure is:

```
localhost/project/shop/
```

There are other pages, `contact.html`, `about.html` etc etc.

I wanted to rewrite the URLs to show it without `.html` so I used the suggestions here:

[How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Most of those didn't worked well, the problem was that it instead taking me to

`localhost/project/shop/about`

to me to

`localhost/about`

So I quit the idea of doing that on the localhost, so I removed the htaccess file and all other links worked fine, except for one `contact.html`, somehow it is cached and now going to `localhost/project/shop/contact.html` still takes redirects me to `localhost/contact`

If I open the localhost in an Incognito tab or if I add `?random=anything...` the links works.

Any idea where I went wrong and how do I fix the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried clearing caches, restarting WAMP server and removing the htaccess from the directory.