# How to remove .html extension from the url

Tags: html

I want to remove the `.html` extension from the url.

**eg** `file:///Users/DivyaGalla/Downloads/deyaPaywebsitee/public/index.html` after removing I want is `./index` only.

I am using cloud functions as server and firebase is the database. I hosted my website using firebase hosting.

When hosting the website it creates a folder that is public folder. It contains all the `.html` extension file.How to remove `.html` file extension from url. I wrongly used `.htaccess` for removing but it is not correct way.

So please any one can suggest me the correct way to remove the url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: once see my updated question

Comment: You questions is 100% duplicate of the existing question I have linked above. Did you check it ?

Comment: I don't want to use Apache server. .htaccess is under a Apache server isn't it?

Comment: Sorry its unclear what you are asking for. If you don't want to use apache server for url manipulation then why did you tag this question as `mod-rewrite` ?

Comment: Firstly what I thought is .htaccess file is used for this so that's why I tagged that tag.

Answer (score 2):

U can use like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

and name as .htaccess in your root path

Comment: OP specified that he is using Firebase Hosting, which does not allow .htaccess. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: okay @ttoshiro may be useful for other :D

Answer (score 2):

"cleanUrls": true

The cleanUrls setting is an optional parameter that, when true, will automatically drop the .html extension from uploaded file URLs. If a .html extension is added, a 301 redirect will be performed to the same path without the .html extension

Comment: I think that using of RewriteEngine will be much better then 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

When loading HTML files from disk (such as with your `file:` path), there is no web server in between the file and the browser.  With no web server, there is nothing to interpret rewrite rules, and thus this is not possible.

Once you do host your content with a web server, you should know that `.htaccess` is just a config file naming convention for Apache HTTPD.  Ideally, you configure your server somewhere else, as Apache will have to parse that file every time something is loaded in that directory otherwise.  This is highly inefficient.

Comment: Is there another method to remove .html file from url

Comment: @vijju Read the first paragraph again where I explain to you why it's not possible without a web server and ask any clarifying questions you have.

Comment: I am using cloud functions as sever and firebase is the database for my website. so I hosted my website into firebase . While hosting the firebase creates a public folder in that .html files are stored. so I placed the .htaccess file in that folder