# Rewrite URL to remove `.html` extension

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the .html extension on my website URL but nothing seems to work. 
**<**[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJS7.png)**>**.
I have made a .htaccess file and put in the following:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

AND

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

but I find that nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: This is related to which server you're using, you'll have to mention or add a tag to say which server it is to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite implementation is fine.

You most likely don't have htaccess `AllowOverride` directives enabled, or possibly mod_rewrite is not switched on.

If you have access to the server configuration and logs it is better to put the rewrite directives in the server configuration file. It is faster, cleaner and avoids possible `AllowOverride` issues. The logs should show exactly what is happening, you can temporarily enable verbose mod_rewrite logging with:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

If you don't have access to the server configuration and logs then you will need to contact your provider. Without access to those it is impossible to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta and then upload your files into the web root without the .html extension

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; UTF-8">
```