# .htaccess only showing files, not actual content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code setup in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

however, when I try to access www.example.com/example, it only shows the files in that page, not actual content. I'm just trying to get it to be www.example.com/example instead of www.example.com/example.html

Comment: Refer to third answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: make sure mod rewrite is enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: The problem still persists, I'm getting the listing directory not actual content

Comment: Your code sample works here. Maybe there is a conflict with the global configuration.

Comment: @janmyszkier, not enabling the mod leads to a 500 error.

Comment: Not entirely sure what I could change to make it work, Namecheap says it has mod rewrite enabled by default

Comment: Also, example.com/index works and shows content just fine, but example.com/blog for example is showing Index of /blog instead of actual content

Comment: @Muchkler is there a file named blog.html?

Comment: @Bajic Yes there is

Comment: shouldn't `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}`  be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`