# URL without .html in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the project folder where i have some html pages and i have the admin folder where i have the login and dashboard pages. The project is in some location http://localhost:8080/index.html. Now if the user types /admin eg. http://localhost:8080/admin i want to show the login page and am not using any backend language, how to do this. 
Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is name of login page in admin folder? Is something like 'login.html'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: @Sagar  it is login.html

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @ Brad  Apache web server

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngnix** for client side project to redirect the request to index.html

```
server_name admin;
 location  /admin/ {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 proxy_redirect    / $request_uri;
}
```

Comment: where i should paste this code and i didn't understand this code

Comment: you should install ngnix and inside the html folder you should paste your project. inside the config file you should add what i have answerd. I hope you know tamil

Comment: can i use this command npm install nginx inside the project folder

Comment: should i paste the code in the nginx.conf  file .I am not using any php code for this

Comment: no php is needed. you can just paste this in your ngnix config. or share me your config file and foder structure

Comment: my folder structure is project index.html, contact.html, about.html ,admin in this folder i have login.html and dashboard.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189242/discussion-between-bear-nithi-and-lakshmi-priya).

Answer (score -1):

If file name is not given in the url then web servers look for index files in this order
index.html
index.htm
default.html
default.htm
home.html
home.htm
Index.html
Index.htm
Default.html
Default.htm
Home.html
Home.htm

rename your login.html file to one of the above.

Comment: The configuration of these pages is anything but universal, and is not guaranteed.

Comment: is there any other way to do

Comment: @lakshmipriya My answer was considering IIS is your web server. May be you should look into apache web server configuration. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex https://www.mkyong.com/apache/how-to-set-change-default-page-in-apache/