# Is there any way to hide the .html extension on html static website?

Tags: html, css

[image: s]

I want to hide those `.html` extensions in the url. Is it possible? How can I hide them?

Comment: Does your server support .htaccess files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Comment: don't get why it was downvoted... when googling it was the first result opposed to the duplicated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the `.html` extension from a html file for example `yoursite.com/wallpaper.html` to `yoursite.com/wallpaper` you have to add the following code inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```