# How to set the default homepage index.html on Google Cloud CDN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, load-balancing, google-cloud-cdn

I configured load balancing and CDN for storage static web pages in Google Cloud, and configured domain name access in load balancing. When I access the domain name in the browser, the domain name suffix always displays "index.html", but I don't want to If you want this suffix, how do you configure it not to display this suffix when you visit in the browser.

Comment: Are you saying you do not want to display the suffix which is `.html` or the entire file `index.html`. You cannot accomplish the first and Cloud Storage is not causing the second. What is the displayed URL when you enter the URL without `index.html`? If you enter `www.example.com/` Google Cloud Storage will return the content of `index.html` but does not redirect your browser to `www.example.com/index.html`. There is something else going on in your browser setup.

Answer (score 2):

The `index.html` suffix appearing in your URL is not a condition of Cloud Load Balancer nor the Cloud CDN. It is a condition presented by your Web Server.
The LB just redirects the request towards the backend services.
I recommend you check this other thread discussions here [how-to-remove-html-from-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url), as it depends of your Web Server application.

For file hosted in a storage bucket, you can control the action by set the `MainPageSuffix`value like:
`gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://www.example.com`

More info and documentation here: [gsutil commands](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) and [tips for buckets as webserver](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tips)

Comment: A web server is not present/involved for Google Cloud Storage static websites.

Comment: For file hosted in a storage bucket, you can control the action by set the `MainPageSuffix`value like:
`gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://www.example.com`

More info and documentation here: [gsutil commands](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web) [tips for buckets as webserver](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tips)

Comment: Those command only set which page to display (default, 404, etc). They do not affect how a URL is displayed in a user's browser.