# how to remove the url extension

Tags: html, url

I am developing a website for myself, pure and without server language.

The urls are as they are called in the a tag, for example: blog / index.html.

Is there anything I can use to change that? I don't want to have to use framework. I would like to know if there is any tool that does this.

What I want to change is the ending. I don't want the extension to appear, just the route

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try create `.htaccess` file on your root folder then paste this

```
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

you can read more about this here https://www.plothost.com/kb/how-to-remove-php-html-extensions-with-htaccess/

EDIT

Since you are using Vercel.com, as per their documentation there's a file config named `vercel.json` you can add this

```
{
  "cleanUrls": true
}
```

the docs said,

When set to true, all HTML files and Serverless Functions will have their extension removed. When visiting a path that ends with the extension, a 308 response will redirect the client to the extensionless path.

for more information pls read their docs here https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/clean-urls

Comment: hmm thats weird, did you put the `.htaccess` file on root folder?

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/htaccess-not-working maybe there's a configuration from your hosting that is not allowed your `.htaccess`

Comment: man, .htaccess only works for apache servers. I am using Vercel as hosting. Do you know what the other configuration files are?

Comment: i read their documentation, there is a `vercel.json` it's similar to `.htaccess` file on apache, i'll update my answer

Comment: Vlw bro for the help, before you post I already found it. Thank you very much for the strength