# If I remove .html from URL will old links still work?

Tags: html, .htaccess

When I first set up my website I forgot to add the code in the .htaccess file to remove the .html in the web page URL.

I would now like to do that but only if the old links with .html in the URL will still work.

So will the old links still work even when I update the .htaccess file to remove the .html from the URL?

Comment: Depends on the htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is YES, they will work, if you edit .htaccess to hide the extension.

You can check more about how it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url).