# Navigate without ".html"

Tags: javascript, html, directory, navigation

This is my current root:

```
main
    → index.html
    → page1.html
```

I would like to navigate the user on `page1.html` when a `button` is clicked. However, what I don't want here is the url to have `page1.html`. It should rather have `page1`

For example, look at this link from discord: https://discord.com/app

They don't have `/app.html` but rather `/app` which makes it easier for users to understand navigations. Similarly for https://stackoverflow.com/tags.

I would like to achieve this using pure `HTML` and/or `JS`. I'm looking for the most efficient and fastest methods to achieve this.

Comment: Just put `page1.html` in a folder named `page1` and rename file to `index.html`.

Comment: I thought of that solution, but isn't there a more efficient method. This would lead me to creating many many folders.

Comment: To achieve this you need to configure the server to do url request mapping to a resource and set the appropriate `content-type` header in response like `text/html` or `application/json`

Comment: In the header or in the html?

Comment: Does this help? [How to remove .html from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .html extension can be removed by using a .htaccess file
*Note: the full name of the file is just .htaccess*

You have to follow these steps:

1. Log in to cPanel account.
2. In the Files section, click on the File Manager icon.
3. Click on the Settings Button in the top right corner.
4. If you want to make changes in the Primary Domain then Click on the radio button next to the Web Root. If changes are to be made on Other Domains, then Click the dropdown menu and find the domain in which changes are to be made.
5. Remember to check the checkbox next to Show Hidden Files. Now click the Save Button to return to the File Manager window.
6. Now you are in the Root Folder of the domain which you have selected to make changes. Search for the .htaccess file and right-click on it. Click on the Edit option in the menu. You can now add code to the .htaccess file.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]
   ```

Click on *Save Changes* and *Close*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), you can do it by this way:

First open your terminal/command prompt and create an npm package and install [express.js](https://expressjs.com/):

```
npm init -y
npm install --save express
```

Create `index.js` and write this code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;

app.use("/", express.static("./main")); // Using index.html on the main page and using the main folder as the folder that contains static files

// Using /page1 route for the ./main/page1.html file
app.get("/page1", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("./main/page1.html");
});

// Starting the server
app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`); });
```

Don't forget to add `/page1` instead of `./page1.html` as the hyperlink to your HTML `<button>`

Now run the index.js file

```
node index.js
```

Now you can see that it is working at `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a solution with pure vanilla JS or simply another technique.