# I am having trouble removing the .html extension from my URLs. I'm getting "Bad Flag Delimiter" in my .htaccess rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, web, cpanel

Per the recommendation in [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) I am trying to rewrite my .htaccess file to remove the .html suffix from my site's urls. For example, I want "my-website.ca/ecology.html" to be shortened to "my-website.ca/ecology". However, I am getting some errors (see below).

I appended the following code to my .htaccess file. (Note: I already had `RewriteEngine On` from previous tinkering.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The results have been... weird. Sometimes it doesn't work, and I'm given a "bad flag delimiter" error. Other times, it works for all but one webpage: ecology.html. When I try to access that, I get a weird page asking me to contact the site's webmaster and the log has a "no matching directoryindex"

I worked out that "ecology.html" had a common name with a folder called "ecology" which I have since renamed to "science". But that didn't fix it.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Folders and files getting confused points towards content negotiation. Turn it off.

Comment: And make sure that you test using a fresh anonymous browser window. So that you are not looking at client side cached responses.