# Remove .PHP and keep query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

My code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php(.*) $1$2 [NC]
```

I am trying to use it so

```
www.example.com/test.php?a=not&b=23
```

shows in the url as:

```
www.example.com/test?a=not&b=23
```

and also no www redirects to www.

My error is:
**`404 not found. The URL /test not found on this server`**

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas as to what? What's wrong?

Comment: I get error: 404 not found.  The URL /test not found on this server.

Comment: This diagnostic information should be in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the flag QSA to your RewriteRule directive:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

QSA stands for "Query String Append".

Comment: So the part to remove the .php extension is correct?!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*).php(.*) $1$2 [NC]
> ```

You have it somewhat backwards. Your rule takes an URL `x.php` and rewrites it to `x`. But `x` does not exist.

Instead you need to do this in two phases:

1. On `x.php`, ask the browser to re-request as just `x` (using `[R=301]`).
2. Rewrite `x` to the real URL `x.php` (rather like you are now, but with `[QSA]` instead of trying to match the querystring yourself).

So, perhaps use something like:

```
# Force browser to use condensed URL form
# (and matches will not fall through to the next rule)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NC]

# Make condensed URL form work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.  BUT it is redirecting to without php in the address bar correctly.

Comment: @David19801: "Something like". You're going to have to continue to debug it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574442/why-does-this-cause-an-infinite-request-loop may be pertinent -- the `NS` flag on the first rule may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewriterules do the exact opposite: when the user requests index.php, they will get redirected to index.

Try something like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# for the non-www to www
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/

# for the non-php to php (if no other file extension supplied)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[A-Z]{3}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [R,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Error again: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.