# Check whether site was redirected in by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a following rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule orders\.html orders.php [L,NC]
```

How can I check in orders.php whether the user entered orders.html or orders.php as the request URL?

I want to redirect user to orders.html if he/she has orders.php in the address bar.

Comment: @Justin: The request from the browser for `orders.php` fires. No rewrite is performed. The PHP script detects that `orders.php` was requested and (presumably with `header("Location: ...")`) asks the browser to redirect to `orders.html`. Then, the request from the browser for `orders.html`, triggering the rewrite rule, internally redirecting to `orders.php` (though the user still sees `orders.html` in the URL bar). I don't see any chance of an infinite redirection here, and your way only redirects the user to a non-existent, non-PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the *originally* requested URI from PHP after a ReWrite:

1. Try `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`. In my experience, Apache's mod_rewrite module populates the `REDIRECT_URL` variable for CGI.
2. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should also be useful.

Do `print_r($_SERVER);` to see all the variables at your disposal.

Comment: REQUEST_URI is all that I need, thanks! Why isn't that in phpinfo()?! I'd looked there before I wrote the post.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to redirect user to orders.html if he/she has orders.php in the address bar

If you are looking for an .htaccess solution, try the code below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if the user requested orders.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /orders\.php [NC]
#301 redirect them to orders.html
RewriteRule . orders.html [L,R=301]

#existing rule to rewrite .html to .php
RewriteRule ^orders\.html$ orders.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `THE_REQUEST` is the only variable that is immutable once set from the original request, so it is not affected by subsequent Rewrites

Comment: Interesting. Do you think then that this might be useful to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574442/why-does-this-cause-an-infinite-request-loop?

Comment: Well, it does not work as intended. It does redirect but after navigating to order.php the address is http://domain.tld/my/full/path/to/file/orders.html (so there is a full path of orders.php file on the server). Maybe I've done something wrong?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it seems relevant so I posted an answer

Comment: @bpiec Does your .htaccess look exactly as above esp the `RewriteBase /` ?