# Redirect all .html extensions on my website to without the extension

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I have hyperlinks on all my pages leading to shop.html and index.html and music.html. Is there a way (without me having to go through every file taking out the `.html`) to redirect all these hyperlinks.
I have had a look at .htaccess:

```
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

But this doesn't seem to help at all!

If I don't have this file I can still remove the extension and the page is working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574442/why-does-this-cause-an-infinite-request-loop

Comment: Your .htaccess is only handling the rules to map the non-html URLs to the html files. See the linked question for how to achieve automatic redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have tried that but nothing changes.

I am just putting the in a file named `.htaccess` in my root folder is that okay?

Comment: this is not what I am looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5730126/2768038 I don't want to have to alter all the links