# How to replace in .htaccess ? on / for get request

Tags: .htaccess

I have a link - https://mysite.ru/blog/show?url=c_plus_plus_krut.

I need what would be - https://mysite.ru/blog/show/c_plus_plus_krut

tried many solutions from the net but fails. The last one was:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([A-z0-9]+)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^show$ /%? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Help me please!

UPD:
noticed that if you add .php to show, it works. But I need to strip the file extension :

https://mysite.ru/blog/show.php/c_plus_plus_krut

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573485/php-htaccess-pretty-url-in-reverse

Comment: Could you please confirm you are hitting url `https://mysite.ru/blog/show/c_plus_plus_krut` in browser? Which you want to serve from `https://mysite.ru/blog/show?url=c_plus_plus_krut` in backend?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 
everything works for me under the current link. But she doesn't look pretty. This will be an article preview. If I understand your question correctly

Comment: Is your htaccess located inside `blog` folder?

Comment: @AmitVerma no, at the root of the site

Comment: Okay if it's in root then your rule's pattern should be `^blog/show/?$` and the destination path should be `/blog/%1?` to redirect to the correct location

Comment: @AmitVerma didn't work if I understood you correctly

Comment: What URL are you going and what error do you get? Please be a bit more specific . This will help us better understand your issue .

Comment: @AmitVerma 
https://mysite.ru/blog/show/c_plus_plus_krut - 404
https://mysite.ru/blog/show.php/c_plus_plus_krut - works, but need to remove .php

Comment: Sorry but `mysite.ru/blog/show.php/c_plus_plus_krut` is a completely different URL and it doesn't match the one your originally added in your question. PS : I just saw that you updated your links in the question.

Comment: @AmitVerma Sorry, but below I have the .htaccess code where the .php extension is hidden. Sorry again. yes i wrote below UPD

Comment: Does this URL work if you type it in your browser? `https://mysite.ru/blog/show?url=c_plus_plus_krut`

Comment: yes it works great. Actually, I need to do it from him https://mysite.ru/blog/show/c_plus_plus_krut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments above, you are looking for a RewriteRule that can internally rewrite your new URL

`https://mysite.ru/blog/show/c_plus_plus_krut` to the old one `https://mysite.ru/blog/show?url=c_plus_plus_krut` .

You can use the following rule for this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog/show/(.+)/?$ /blog/show.php?url=$1 [L]
```

And to access your files without using .php at the end, you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Here is it all together :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog/show/(.+)/?$ /blog/show.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: if I just want to go to domain.com/blog/ ?
/blog/ would be the wordpress path